# SCTP message is not getting initiated

Tags: sctp

Trying to initiate the SCTP association, but no message is getting initiated.
Checked in the redhat linux machine, couldn't see sctp.

## checksctp

checksctp: Protocol not supported

lsmod | grep sctp

lksctp-tools-1.0.17-2.el7.x86_64 package is installed in server.
Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Does the kernel support SCTP?

Comment: How to check this? I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

To get SCTP working usually needs the module to be loaded into the kernel, and also for some app protocols (such as DTLS) you will need to enable auth chunk support too.

You can temporarily load the sctp module from the command line:
`modprobe sctp` but to ensure it survives a reboot, you'll also need to add it to the modules startup [1].

Then to enable auth chunks from the command line: `sysctl -w net.sctp.auth_enable=1` and as before, if you want the setting to survive a reboot, you'll need to add it to the sysctl startup [2].

Generally, with both of those enabled, it'll all just work fine.

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/managing-kernel-modules_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel

[2] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/working_with_sysctl_and_kernel_tunables